# Displaying XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to access the xml data from http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS523en-GB.xml but can't seem to retrieve it correctly. I don't think it has anything to do with the structure of the data however. How can I retrieve and display the data?

```
<?php
$fhrsid = 'FHRSID';

$LocalAuthorityBusinessID = 'LocalAuthorityBusinessID';

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS523en-GB.xml");
echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $data)

{
    echo "FHRSID: ".$data->$fhrsid."<br />";
    echo "LocalAuthorityBusinessID : ".$data->$LocalAuthorityBusinessID." <br />";
    echo "BusinessName : ".$data->BusinessName." <br />";
    echo "BusinessType : ".$data->BusinessType." <br />";
    echo "BusinessTypeID : ".$data->BusinessTypeID." <br />";
    echo "AddressLine1 : ".$data->AddressLine1." <br />";
    echo "AddressLine2 : ".$data->AddressLine2." <br />";
    echo "<hr/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
print_r($xml);
```

output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ExtractDate] => 2015-04-25
            [ItemCount] => 1881
            [ReturnCode] => Success
        )

    [EstablishmentCollection] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [EstablishmentDetail] => Array
                (
                    //...
```

And you will see the structure of your xml and you will see that you have to change your foreach header to this:

```
foreach($xml->EstablishmentCollection->EstablishmentDetail as $data)
```

**EDIT:**

Also as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966323/displaying-xml-using-php/29966403?noredirect=1#comment48060779_29966403) from [@hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre), you should use [`asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php):

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

To see the full and entire xml.

Comment: Please also share the information that it won't show the whole picture and to see all XML, `$xml->asXML()` should be used.

Comment: @hakre You're right :) (I think there is even an answer about this with: *You should never trust the output of print_r() or var_dump()*)

Comment: Especially not with SImpleXMLElement (or say a PDO connection when you expect that print_r then shows you the database data, or ... .). :)